# The use of “troop” for “trooper” by the media

Tags: meaning, etymology

What led to this new usage? Are there any clues as to its origin (i.e., is there a particular journalist or political figure who introduced it)? Is it on the upswing as I suspect (are there any reputable dictionaries which attest it)?

### Background

For most of my life, I understood *troop* to mean a body of soldiers, as attested by *Etymonline.com*:

> **troop (n.)**
> 1540s, “body of soldiers,” from Middle French *troupe*, from Old French *trope* “band of people, company, troop” (13c.), probably from Frankish **throp* “assembly, gathering of people” (cf. Old English *ðorp*, Old Norse *thorp* “village,” see *thorp*). OED derives the French word from Latin *troppus* “flock,” which is of unknown origin but may be from the Germanic source.[¹](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=troop)

But in the past twenty or years or so I have noticed *troop* used, particularly in journalism, to mean an individual (a “trooper”). This usage seems to be on the upswing. Here are two typical examples from last year:

> ***CBS News***
> Taliban insurgents killed *10 Afghan troops* in an ambush in western Herat province, police and government officials said Tuesday, as *one U.S. troop* was killed in an attack on the other side of the country.[²](http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-202_162-57538256/u.s-troop-killed-in-afghanistan-attack-amid-fears-that-militants-regrouping-in-rugged-eastern-areas-along-pakistan-border/)
>
> ***The Huffington Post***
> Among the combat wounded from all the military services are 1,572 patients with major limb amputations, including *486 wounded troops* with multiple amputations. These numbers do not include those who suffered the loss of fingers or toes.[³](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/11/07/iraq-afghanistan-amputees_n_2089911.html) [*emphasis added*]

I have not yet seen the true singular form meaning an individual attested by any dictionaries, but it is definitely in use as shown above.

Comment: This is from kids not listening to enough Iron Maiden.

Comment: @Kaz ...or Abba.

Comment: Conjecture: "15 _of the_ troops were killed" became "15 troops were killed".

Comment: The word troop is not just a body of soldiers, generally. It refers to particular forms of military unit in particular military branches, usually equivalent to a platoon. Today, a troop is defined differently in different armed forces. This article explains it in detail http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troop

Comment: @Tristan Yes, I understand that the *particular* body of soldiers it refers to can differ from force to force. But I think it will just confuse the question if I add that amount of detail.

Comment: Ed, that's why I mentioned this in the form of a comment, rather than an answer. In case you didn't know, but also for the benefit of anyone else who would view this page. Interestingly, the word troop is not only used in the context of armies, but other kinds of armed forces, as well. The Royal Marines are an example of that.

Comment: @Tristan I should let you know that comments are temporary and not good for open ended discussion. They are used to guide the OP to improve the Q (or A) and, though some comments do manage an awfully long shelf life, they are always subject to cleanup by moderators. A great place to carry on open discussion is the chatroom at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage. Come join us there!

Comment: Would it be better if I posted that information, as an answer?

Comment: @Tristan If it answers the question.

Comment: I had assumed the troop in the slogan "Support Our Troops" was equivalent to a soldier in "Support Our Soldiers". Perhaps this sort of thing is contributing to the change in meaning.

Comment: Relevant visual thesaurus article: "[A Troop of One](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/dictionary/a-troop-of-one/)"
November 11, 2009, by Neal Whitman

Answer (score 4):

OED has a citation:

> **troop, *n.***
>   **2** *pl.*
>   **a.** Armed forces collectively. Also *fig.*
>   1598 R. Barret *Theorike & Pract. Mod. Warres* v.136 : Fraunce, and Flanders, too full of his pencionary troops.

So its use as a plural is long attested. However there is also

> **Draft Additions 1993**
>   Chiefly in *sing.* [Irreg. < the collect. plural: in some cases perhaps abbrev. of ***Trooper n.,***] A member of a troop of soldiers (or other servicemen); a soldier, a trooper. *colloq.* (chiefly *Mil.*)

and that is attested in quotation marks in 1832, and without in 1947.