# Is "many" grammatically viable in front of plural-only nouns?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, determiners, countable-nouns, pluralia-tantum

There are certain nouns in English that are plural only and have no singular equivalents. Some such as *trousers, scissors, pajamas, pantyhose, shears, binoculars, headphones, etc.* can be singularized with *pair* or *set*, which could mean that *many* could be grammatically placed before them.

> I have many pairs of trousers.

But not all nouns are like these. Take *clothes, goods, thanks, shenanigans, antics* for example. While there seem to be quite many citations on Google Books for *many clothes, many goods, many thanks, many shenanigans, many antics*:

> And then I do what any self-respecting New York woman with too many books and too **many clothes** does when she's frustrated. (*So Many Books, So Little Time: A Year of Passionate Reading* by Sara Nelson)
>
> An IPC is a broad classification that contains **many goods** or services. (*How Many Trademarks Does it Take to Protect a Brand?: The Optimal Number of Trademarks, Branding Strategy and Brand Performance* by Mary Sullivan)
>
> Walter's attraction to Hildy was clear through his **many antics** to regain her affection both during and after their divorce. (*Classical Hollywood Comedy* by Alan Jenkins)

I'm still not 100% confident that *many* can be used like this. Is there an authoritative source on how to deal with specifically *many* and pluralia tantum?

Comment: You _can_ be 100% confident that _many thanks_, _many clothes_ and the like are idiomatic and correct.

Comment: A: Many of (= a lot of) the classroom scissors are missing. B: How many? C: Oh,  about seven or eight.

Comment: What would you use instead of "many" in the question form (B)?

Comment: "Good" and "headphone" often occur in the singular.

Comment: [*Antic*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antic), which you use in your third quote, is a straightforward countable noun.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the exact *plurale tantum*? People have already given you  examples of plural-only nouns you can use *many* with. However, *He is suffering from the blues*, but not **They are suffering from many blues*;  And *He studied his surroundings carefully*, but not **They studied their many surroundings carefully.*

Comment: @PeterShor In those cases it's not related to a mismatch between *many* and what the OP considers to be "uncountable" plural-only nouns. First, it's the fact that the definite article is part of the idiom *the blues*. You can't swap the definite article there for another Determiner. Consider * *They're suffering from some/several/these/enough blues.* The second example only doesn't work because of the pragmatic interpretation you're likely to give to the semantic relations there.  *They studied the different students in their many different surroundings* is fine.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore: Maybe. But *he's suffering from those winter blues* and *he's suffering from those jailhouse blues* sound perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, *those* seems to work fine there too.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that most of these uses are constructions, idioms, and fixed phrases. The fact is that _much_ and _many_ are far more comfortable in negative contexts, though they're not quite NPIs because they have too many special uses. Sentences like ?*_She has much money_ are clearly awful and don't occur except in discussions like this. I suspect (I haven't looked carefully) that this is what happens when an NPI is either developing or losing its negativity. The availability of _a lot_, which isn't negative and doesn't distinguish sg from pl, mass from count, undoubtedly helps.

Comment: ' ... many headphones' is reasonably common on the internet. // One needs to categorise carefully: '_cattle_ (a) is singular in form (**no** -s, -i, -en ...) / (b) takes a plural verb form (the cattle are lowing) / (c) is non-count (*3/17/a dozen cattle were ...) (may not be the case for large rounded numbers) / (d) applies to an etically countable referent (21 cows plus 1 bull)'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: *Cattle* is only non-count in certain dialects. Nobody says *one cattle* (they'd say *one cow* or *one bull*), but *a thousand cattle* is almost as common as the possibly more grammatical *a thousand head of cattle*. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thousand+cattle%2Cthousand+head+of+cattle&year_start=1750&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Peter Shor Hence the caveat 'may not be the case for large rounded numbers'. See [Is the term 'quasi-count noun usage' used in a grammar or articles?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385046/is-the-term-quasi-count-noun-usage-used-in-a-grammar-or-articles).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You'd say "twenty-three cattle" ... being rounded has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Peter Shor '[37]i _cattle, livestock, police, poultry(1), vermin_ ... The items in [37i] cannot be used with low numerals, but are found with high round numerals' [[CGEL](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385046/is-the-term-quasi-count-noun-usage-used-in-a-grammar-or-articles)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: For *cattle* and *police*, I'm pretty sure that only holds for some dialects. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twenty+policemen+were%2Ctwenty+cattle+were%2Ctwenty+head+of+cattle+were%2Ctwenty+police+were%2Ctwenty+police+officers+were&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10).

Comment: ... and chasing results for say 371 cattle/police is futile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An authoritative source is Q*uirk et al. (1985). A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*.

The part of the book dealing with *number* has a section (5.77) with the title (Bb) **Pluralia tantum ending in -s** (page 301). The section lists over sixty such nouns, together with one or more phrases or clauses exemplifying them.

It does not specifically deal with the use of *many* with such nouns, but it does include *many* in three exemplifications:

- Many congratulations on your birthday.
- Many thanks for...
- Many troops were sent overseas.

In my estimation a majority of the other words listed in the *pluralia tantu*m section cannot be preceded by *many*. So no useful generalisation can be applied to such nouns. You can, however, be 100% confident that *many* can precede some of them.

Comment: Can you provide two or three examples where  the determiner *many* would be ungrammatical? I can't think of any, unless by adding the countable expression "pairs of" to those singular objects which come into pairs.

Comment: Even a musical genre such as *the blues* if used as a noun adjunct sits comfortably well with *many*, e.g. Of the [many blues artists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chicago_blues_musicians#H), who is your favourite? P.S Isn't "troop" a normal noun and countable?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. Quirk deals with words like _scissors_ and _headphones_ in a separate section called __summation plurals__, noting that the most common of these are either _Tools and instruments_ or _Articles of dress_. As for a _pluralia tantum_ which does not permit _many_, Quirk lists _brains=intelligence_. E.g. _You need brains to get into Oxford_. Another example is _looks_: _?She is known for her many good looks_. Quirk lists the _pt_ word _troops_ as synoymous with _soldiers_. The singular _troup_ is a collection of soldiers, and is thus countable in the usual way.

Comment: I've always wondered about these people who have more than one brain! Those examples are pretty interesting. Wouldn't it be nice to have them in your post? (But I'm not sure I agree with Quirk et al (or CGEL)  that *brains* in that sense is either plural or countable, despite its morphology. I'd expect to see "and brains is what I have", not "and brains are what I have", which seems to be saying something different! The same goes for *guts* etc. "Guts is what you need" v. "Guts are what you need"  - everyone needs the latter. My inner jury is out.)

Comment: @Araucaria. There's a Steve Martin film called _The Man with Two Brains_, so such people do exist! I take your point about brains, but "_Brains are what you need_" is more acceptable to me than "_Brains is what you need_". I may add a few more examples to my answer if OP requests it.

Comment: You did cite an authoritative source, but it doesn't seem to be "an authoritative source on how to deal with specifically _many_ and pluralia tantum". Am I missing something here?

Comment: @JK2. I agree that Quirk does not specifically address the "_many_" question. I wrote as much in my answer. But one can extrapolate from Quirk's three exemplifications that _many_ can indeed premodify a pluralia tantum. This is evidently sufficient to satisfy the OP. If you can find a more specific analysis of the issue, I and, presumably also the OP, will be very glad to know of it.

Comment: I don't have any source, but off the top of my head, it seems only natural that plural nouns that are legitimately non-count cannot be modified by _many_, because if you can't count them at all you shouldn't be able to add _many_ either. Simple as that.

Comment: @JK2. Yes, but how is the learner to know whether a pluralia tantum is "legitimately non-count". For example, how about _pains=care/trouble_ in _He took many pains to please his boss_. Or _manners=social behaviour_ in _I dislike many of his manners_.

Comment: I think learners would eventually have to learn the usage of individual pluralia tantum. But the question of whether the noun in question is "legitimately non-count" or not should provide at least some guidance. For example, your _brains_ example is a good candidate of being "legitimately non-count" as it's hard to figure out why you need the plural form _brains_ there. On the other hand, "looks" is not quite at the same level of being non-count. So, I think you can say _She is known for sharing many of her looks on Instagram_, where you can see why you need the plural form. Just my two cents.

Comment: @JK2. I fully agree with your first sentence. A case in point is _looks_. The pt _looks_ in "_She has good looks_", is largely synonymous with "_general appearance_". This is different from the _looks_ in "_many of her looks on Instagram_". The English learner has to learn the individual usages, as you point out. As for _brains_, the plural could be assumed in a statement such as "_We need brains for our next team project._" Anyway, our little exchange on this comment thread has been interesting, as are your many questions elesewhere on the site.

Comment: @JK2 at this point I think the chance of a specific source is pretty much zero. At least this is better than nothing.

Comment: @Shoe "He discovered at last that she had outgrown his liking. She had borne ten children and had lost many of her good looks, was growing old, in fact," says a letter written by Edward Dutton Cook describing Charles Dickens’s troubled relationship with his wife Catherine. I'm not sure if this would be idiomatic in Present-day English, though.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw You're right. The chances are very slim to none that one would find any reliable reference on the matter, the reason being that pluralia tantum, depending on how you define the term, can include so many different kinds of plural nouns from _scissors_ to _clothes_ to _thanks_ to _brains_ to _looks_ to many more, so much so that it's futile to investigate any coherent behavior of pluralia tantum with respect to their countability and thus to their acceptability with _many_.

Comment: @JK2. Yes, that is the problem. In her entry on _pluralia tantum_ in the _Cambridge Dictionary of English Grammar_ Peters states "_Some grammarians reserve it (the term 'pluralia tantum') for aggregates or composites like 'arrears, surroundings'; others apply it also to bipartites or other summation plurals (e.g. scissors, trousers)._" Note: the brackets in the Peters quote are mine.

Answer (score 6):

The Original Poster's diligent research has provided us with a clear answer to the main question. *Many* is used frequently in front of plural only nouns. And, as demonstrated, it's used by respectable published authors in edited books from reputable publishers. This settles the issue decisively.

The subsidiary question, then, is whether there are [fetishistic sadomasochists<sup>1</sup>](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/usage_perverts.pdf) who have deemed this a 'rule' of English in the face of all the evidence? *Thou shalt not use 'many' in front of plurale tantum! You have been a naughty, naughty published author. Now where is my riding crop? ...* The answer to that question is : no. The dogmatists haven't got there yet. Best not start giving them ideas!

---

<sup>1</sup> For the origin of this description see Professor Geoffrey K. Pullum's [influential paper](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/usage_perverts.pdf) published by the Oxford University Press:

> Pullum, Geoffrey K. 'Catering to perverts', in Ingrid Tieken-Boon van Ostade (ed.), *English Usage Guides: History, Advice, Attitudes* (Oxford, 2017; online edn, Oxford Academic, 21 Dec. 2017), https://doi.org/10.1093/oso/9780198808206.003.0011, accessed 16 Sept. 2022.

Comment: I suppose you were forced to use  CW seeing as recently  comments get deleted without warning and any useful information is lost.

Comment: Psst... we know you are *here* but let's keep pretending you're not :)

Comment: I don't understand the need for a CW mark on this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/431015)

Comment: @Chenmunka You may not like the answer. It was not designed to put those people who are actively anti-educational in a warm and fuzzy light. However, it directly answers both prongs of the OP's question. Is it not ungrammatical, and is it not ungrammatical according to the dogma of the teachers in the OP's country (his description), or anywhere else. If you disagree, explain exactly how.

Comment: One small note: I didn't suggest it's a "rule" not to use *many* before pluralia tantrum, but apparently some users here have taken that as true. I removed that problematic mention from my question.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw I think it's implied by your section "*I'm still not 100% confident that* many *can be used like this. After all, the typical English teacher in my country loves to beat into their students' heads dogmatic structures like the subjunctive mood, but actual native usage proves such dogma is frequently flouted.*" It's hard to think what you might mean by it *not* being able to be used like this, especially given the juxtaposition of the dogmatic teachers comment, unless you were talking about a prescriptive rule of some sort. Because, well, it's used like this!

Comment: Suppose. That part's gone too.

Comment: @Chenmunka I think the reason why Araucaria's answer was written only tangentially to the call of the question was because the question was written in a way that it couldn't be answered properly. The question is entirely based on the false premise that _many_ cannot combine with plural-only nouns. How can you directly answer a question that is based on a false premise? You've got only two options: a. Answer the question only obliquely (as Araucaria did). or b. Bluntly call the premise false (like I did).

Comment: @listeneva dude, enough with this "false premise" drivel. I get it, you can't answer. I've already gotten rid of that "premise", if that makes you happy. Feel free to closevote once the bounty expires. There's already much better answers and comments than yours, by people who have no problem just saying "yes" or "no" rather than wasting time trying to psychoanalyzing me. I've known which answer I'll award, it turned out that's actually possible

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw No you haven't. Your question is still based on that premise. And I'm not entitled to closevote a question. As for the bounty, do you really think I care?

Comment: @listeneva No, why would I really think of any of your concerns at all? I meant there's no need for you to go on this pointless crusade against the figments of my imagination. I've finally had time to verify the source provided by Shoe. It's settled, I picked my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> There are certain nouns in English that are plural only and have no singular equivalents. Some such as *trousers, scissors, pajamas, pantyhose, shears, binoculars, headphones,* etc.
> [but…] *clothes, goods, thanks, shenanigans, antics* …

All the examples of [plurale tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) cited by the O.P, with the exemption of the AmEng *panthose*, end with the suffix -s. Many of these words are considered plural because they are made up of a pair of something: trousers have two trouser legs, (note the singular *trouser* used as a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)); *field glasses*, also called [binoculars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binoculars), consist of two telescopes; scissors have two blades, and so forth. As a result, the question form *How **many**…* can be used in place of  *How many **pairs of**…*  even when the noun is a plurale tantum that represents a single object.

*How many clothes/ pajamas/ trousers/ headphones* did you buy at the sale?

As well as that, we use plural verbs and pronouns for questions and answers; e.g. “Where **are** my tweezers?” “**They**’re in the bathroom cabinet.”

In the comment section, users have reminded the OP  the following

- You can be 100% confident that *many thanks, many clothes* and the like are idiomatic and correct. @Kate Bunting

and a few of these *pluralia tantum* actually have singular forms:

- *Antic*, which you use in your third quote, is a straightforward countable noun. @Araucaria

also [Shenanigan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shenanigan),  [pajama](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pajama) (We're invited to a *pajama party* down at Deirdre's), and [tweezer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tweezer).

The only exception I can think of where *many* is used with a singular noun or pronoun is in the somewhat outdated literary form, **many a**

> They walked on the moors **many a time.**
> *Many a man* has tried but few men have succeeded.
> *Many a little* makes a mickle.
> An over confidence has wrecked [many a ship](https://books.google.it/books?id=VpfQzoDv6qUC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%22has%20wrecked%20many%20a%20ship,%20and%20lost%20many%20a%20battle%22&source=bl&ots=DfGL41J4e6&sig=ACfU3U0BgglGHqnghsEg16IbpKSkczCEiQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis2avO-6P6AhWQQvEDHSyhBYIQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22has%20wrecked%20many%20a%20ship%2C%20and%20lost%20many%20a%20battle%22&f=false), and lost many a battle.

Comment: You're not suggesting that questions dealing with quantities cannot begin with _How many pairs of…?_, are you?

Comment: @listeneva No, I'm not. I was trying to explain that the question form "How many" can be used in placed of "How many pairs of" even when the noun is clearly a plurale tantum. I'll edit and clarify later.

Comment: Thought so, but just double-checking...//BTW, I don't think the question is about whether _many_ can be used with a singular noun. The OP's erroneously assuming that _many_ cannot combine with plural-only nouns, which isn't true at all. How can you answer a question that's based on a false premise other than answering a different question (like you did)?

Comment: @listenevalisten I did answer the question but  I *also* provided an example where "many + plural noun/pluralism tantum" rule is defied.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be based on this mistaken premise:

> ...unlike *a lot* or *lots*, *many* is almost always said to be compatible with only countable nouns...

Says who?

Countable nouns, by definition, are nouns that can be counted-- that is, nouns that can be determined by cardinal numerals *one*, *two*, *three*, etc.

*Many* is compatible not only with countable nouns, but also with plural-only nouns. For example, *people* meaning "persons" is a plural-only noun, so you can't say **one people*, but you can certainly say *many people* in appropriate context.

> *There are so many people here.*

There is no answering your question directly without first questioning the validity of its premise.

---

Now the question has been edited to remove the premise, at least the explicit statement that *many* cannot combine with plural-only nouns. Yet the OP is still based on the same false premise now implied in the last paragraph:

> I'm still not 100% confident that *many* can be used like this. Is there an authoritative source on how to deal with specifically *many* and pluralia tantum?

It's abundantly clear from all the comments and answers so far that the OP's confidence, or lack thereof, on the matter is entirely unfounded. How can you properly answer a question that is based on a pure speculation that turns out to be false, nothing more than a figment of the OP's imagination?

If there's any post that needs to be closed, I strongly feel this is the one. I wonder where all the aggressive closevoters are.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139356/discussion-on-answer-by-listeneva-is-many-grammatically-viable-in-front-of-plu).